# Sub select of row that has max column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do something that sounds really simple but I have been going round in circles a little with it..

I have a stored procedure that currently works as required missing only one bit of functionality, to return a name for a corrosponding max calculation...

So I return

average calculation & 
max calculation but want to return 'the name from another column' for the max value.

Here is an example of my SP, apologies that it may not seem very natural as I have had to rename and omit non relevant bits so may seem a little contrived::

```
SELECT  
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(TABLE1.TotalCapacityPercentageUsage / TABLE1.TotalSnapshotsForTimeSegment), 2), 0.0) AS TotalAvgCapacityPercentageUsage,
    IFNULL(ROUND(MAX(TABLE1.MaxCapacityPercentageUsage), 2), 0.0) AS TotalMaxCapacityPercentageUsage,
     -- TODO return the QueuesTmp.QueueName for max calculation (This could be more than one row, so I was going to use something like the following:
     -- (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(QueuesTmp.QueueName SEPARATOR ' ') to ensure only one field is returned.. 

    FROM TABLE1
    INNER JOIN QueuesTmp ON QueuesTmp.QueueID = TABLE1.QueueID
    RIGHT JOIN TimesTmp ON TABLE1.TimeSegment = TimesTmp.QuarterHour AND
                           TABLE1.Date = DATE(TimesTmp.StartOfRangeUTC)
    GROUP BY TimesTmp.QuarterHour;
```

I started by doing a Sub select but it seems I would then have to repeat all of the Joins, WHERE and Group By (Seems this is not even possible because that's what having is for)..

Can anybody guide me in the right direction as to how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

**WORKING SOLUTION**

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT QueuesTmp.QueueName ORDER BY MYCOLUMN DESC 
                     SEPARATOR ':') AS MaxColumnQueueName,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'm on the right way. You need the `QueueName` of that row with the max - calculation. So use the group_concat with an `ORDER BY` of this calculation and get with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` the first element of this list.

```
substring_index(
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT QueuesTmp.QueueName ORDER BY `maxCalculation` DESC) SEPARATOR ':',
    ':',
    1
)
```

Additional question.
Sorry unfortunately the max comment space has reached. Here a query.
I used your example - query for sub and select the queueId as comma-separated list and the max(maxColumn) as additional.
After that I join to queue-table again with queueId and maxColumn. I can't guarantee if that works.

```
SELECT 
    sub.TotalAvgCapacityPercentageUsage,
    sub.TotalMaxCapacityPercentageUsage,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT QueuesTmp.QueueName ORDER BY MYCOLUMN DESC SEPARATOR ':') AS MaxColumnQueueName
FROM(
    SELECT  
        TimesTmp.QuarterHour,
        IFNULL(
            ROUND(
                AVG(
                    TABLE1.TotalCapacityPercentageUsage / 
                    TABLE1.TotalSnapshotsForTimeSegment
                ), 
                2
            ), 
            0.0
        ) AS TotalAvgCapacityPercentageUsage,
        IFNULL(
            ROUND(
                MAX(TABLE1.MaxCapacityPercentageUsage), 
                2
            ), 
            0.0
       ) AS TotalMaxCapacityPercentageUsage,
       max(QueuesTmp.maxColumn) AS maxColumn,
       group_concat(DISTINCT QueueID) AS QueueID
    FROM TABLE1
    INNER JOIN QueuesTmp 
        ON QueuesTmp.QueueID = TABLE1.QueueID
    RIGHT JOIN TimesTmp 
        ON TABLE1.TimeSegment = TimesTmp.QuarterHour 
        AND TABLE1.Date = DATE(TimesTmp.StartOfRangeUTC)
    GROUP BY TimesTmp.QuarterHour
) AS sub
LEFT JOIN QueuesTmp 
    ON QueuesTmp.QueueID IN(sub.QueueID)
    AND QueuesTmp.maxColumn = sub.maxColumn
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you soo much for your reply. I think that seems to work great. I had to make a minor change as it wasn't quite syntactically correct and I also wanted to return all the queue names that matched the max calculation but seems to work great. I will post my working example as an edit to my question.. Can I please just confirm something with you though. I simply ordered by my column not a ORDER  BY MAX(COLUMN) is that correct? Also the select is constrained by the group by that the original query is doing I hope? Would seem weird if it wasn't.

Comment: No problem you can order by what you want. My example is based on your comment inside the given query. 
Thanks for syntax hint for my example, I correct it.

Comment: Hi sorry I know that I have accepted your answer but it hasn't got my quite what I need. It is the right direction though. So now as it stands it returns me a string with the queue names in desc order based on their max value, great! However I want it to only return me the Queue(s) (there is likely to be more than one) that have a max value that is equal to the max.. So its almost like I need to do a WHERE in my group_concat that will only return me queues WHERE there max value is equal to a calculation of the MAX, e.g. WHERE MaxColumn = MAX(MaxColumn).. I can't see how to do this, any ideas.T

Comment: You have to subselect the MAX(MaxColumn), then you rejoin and use your `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(QueuesTmp.MaxColumn = sub.MaxColumn,QueuesTmp.QueueName,NULL) ORDER BY MYCOLUMN DESC SEPARATOR ':')`

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean but how do you do the sub select because I want to do that in the context of my group by and other joins or do I have to write all of those joins again? The MaxColumn also doesn't live in QueuesTmp it lives in TABLE1 where by QueuesTmp and TABLE1 join via a common key (QueueID) just to complicate things slightly more.

Comment: I've extended my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks i'm playing around with that design but haven't quite got it working yet. I think this should work with a bit of perseverance! Much appreciated.